# Blank window opening in CEF browser

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to open a new window on click of a link using CEF.
I have given the href and target as `_blank` in my HTML.

New page is opening fine when Internet is available, but opens a blank window when connection is down. I tried debugging and as far as I understand , if the OnBeforePopUp function returns false, there should be no problems.

My HTML code line is

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" title="Google" aria-label="Google" id="Google"><span class="sr-only">Click here for Google</span> Help</a>
```

and in my code,

```
public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browser, string url, ref int x, ref int y, ref int width, ref int height)
{
       return false;
}
```

Comment: add codes to your question

Comment: What exactly is your understanding of `return false` in this context? To cancel opening a popup you `return true`. For most of the `API` `return false` will invoke the default behavior, which in this case is to open a popup.

Comment: yes.. the pop-up is opening, but as a blank page.I need to proper errors when network is down.

Comment: Currently the only way to get full control of a popup is to cancel it's creation and spawn a new instance of `ChromiumWebBrowser` loading in the required url. Then you can hook the `LoadError` event and act appropriately.

Much of the popup functionality isn't exposed. There is a major redevelopment under-way, though it's nowhere near production ready.

Answer (score 0):

CEF will obviously show blank page when url is down. What you can do is, design one html page to show when site is down and show that static page in CEF.